# Type void not assignable to 'IntrinsicAttributes & Dispatch<SetStateAction<>>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, type-conversion

It's my first contact with typescript and I am stucked with the following error:

Error :Type '{ setTasks: void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Dispatch<SetStateAction<IStudy[]>>'. Property 'setTasks' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Dispatch<SetStateAction<IStudy[]>>'

My app:

```
function App() {
  const [tasks,setTasks] = useState<IStudy[] | []>([]);

  return (
    <div className={style.AppStyle}>
      <Form setTasks={setTasks(tasks)}/>
      <List tasks={tasks}/>
      <Timer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

my form:

```
const Form = (setTasks : React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<IStudy[]>>)=> {

  const [study,setStudy] = useState('')

  function addTask(event: React.FormEvent){
    event.preventDefault();
    setTasks((oldstudies) => {[...oldstudies, {oldstudies}]});
  }
  return(
    <form className={style.newTask} onSubmit={addTask}>
      <div className={style.inputContainer}>
        <label htmlFor="task">
          Add your new study task
        </label>
        <input 
          type="text"
          name="task"
          id="task"
          value ={study}
          onChange = {e => setStudy(e.target.value)}
          placeholder="What do you want to study?"
          required
        />

      </div>
      .................... )}
```

Interface:

```
export interface IStudy {
  study:string,
  }
```

While I can undestand what is happening(set task void type does not exist on the type assigned in typescript), I could not understand how to create a proper solution for this error.How can I assign this type properly in the interface or in the arguments?

Comment: What is `setTasks((oldstudies) => {[...oldstudies, {oldstudies}]});` supposed to do?

Comment: It's the destructuring from useState from app, i am trying to add the study to the List

Answer (score 0):

Missing destructuring here (props always passed as object):

```
const Form = ({ setTasks }: { setTasks: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<IStudy[]>> })=> {
```

You don't need `[]` in the generic:

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState<IStudy[]>([]);
```

You shouldn't call `setTasks` when trying to pass it to `Form`:

```
<Form setTasks={setTasks} />
```